# I need scaleType="matrix" in order to drag object around in an ImageView. I want the image to be smaller using the default fit_center

Tags: android, imageview

I need to make in XML scaleType="matrix" in order to move the image around in the ImageView, but the image is too big, scaleType="fit_center" make the image just the right size. How do I have scaleType="fit_center" or something to that effect and still can drag the image around.

Here is the java code:

```
private ImageView imageView;
private Matrix matrix=new Matrix();
private Matrix savedMatrix=new Matrix();
private PointF start=new PointF();//PointF holds 2 coordinates
private Bitmap bmap;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.photo);
    imageView.setOnTouchListener(this);

}
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
    imageView=(ImageView)v;
    switch(event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN://first pointer down
            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
            float dx=event.getX()-start.x;
            float dy=event.getY()-start.y;
            matrix.postTranslate(dx,dy);
            break;
    }//switch
    imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
    bmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageView.getWidth(), imageView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmap);
    imageView.draw(canvas);
    return true;
}
}
```